# C# - Get the inversed base of a Math.Pow function

Tags: c#

Suppose that i've the next:

```
  double a = Math.Pow(b, c);
```

And i know 'a' and 'c' but i need to get 'b', like:

```
  double b = a ??? c;
```

Comment: So you want to get the n-th root of something? Should be as simple as `b = Math.Pow(a, 1.0/c);`

Comment: Do note that this equation has multiple (c) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Do `Math.Pow` of the inverse of `c`:

```
double b = Math.Pow(a, 1.0 / c);
```